# Can you hit two players with one bullet?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

I wonder if it is possible to hit two players with one bullet, if they are standing/walking behind each other.

I dont ask about shotguns which have a wide range.
But what about the other weapons (especially sniper rifles). Can they penetrate a player and also hit the player behind them with the same bullet?

I saw that here are some questions like this for other games in which this is possible but i wonder if this is also possible in pubg, and if so, under which circumstances? (specific weapons, armor, ...)

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen people down multiple players with one shot of a shotgun, though technically none of the shotgun pellets went through the one player and into the other, it was just the spread of the pellets.  So I think it's possible to get 2 kills with one shot with a shotgun, but not by shooting through one player and into the other.  [Here is a video](https://youtu.be/mdwIgc8BbGw?t=6s) of this happening.  It appears one player goes down, while his teammate dies, and then the other one dies from begin down without a teammate.  I assume in solo this would result in 2 immediate kills

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can not hit more than one player with a single bullet in PU Battlegrounds.**

As of Jan 5th 2018 PUBG only has a very limited amount of bullet penetration physics, limited to "doors, water, and wooden shacks" ([source](https://pubg.gamepedia.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions_(FAQ)#cite_note-17)).

Bullets, and [crossbow bolts](https://youtu.be/UFlaH5cCwLM?t=152), do not pass through other players. In fact bullets [will not even pass through the dead body of another player](https://youtu.be/LKVb-Ed9FqM?t=43).

So unfortunately, no collateral kills for the foreseeable future.